# Split a File by Grouping In C#

Tags: c#, file

I have a pipe delimited file that has a file name in one of the sections.  I would like to split that file up into multiple files for each file name.  Can someone point me in the right direction of how I would do this in C#.

Here is the example of the file.

```
A|File1
B|File1
C|File1
D|File2
E|File2
F|File2
G|File3
H|File3
I|File3
```

I would like to have three files.

```
A|File1
B|File1
C|File1
...saved as File1

D|File2
E|File2
F|File2
...saved as File2

G|File3
H|File3
I|File3
...saved as File3
```

From what I read here, this can be done by using LINQ, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-split-a-file-into-many-files-by-using-groups-linq.  In this documentation, there is some pseudo query code for the variable groupQuery.  What I do not understand is how to write this query for the file type above to get a distinct list of file names from the files.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note, here is the solution.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileSplitter
{
    class SplitWithGroups
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] myfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\FileSplitter\TestFile.txt");
          
            

            // Group the names by the first letter in the last name.  
            var groupQuery = from filename in myfile
                             let n = filename.Split('|')[1]
                             group filename by n into g
                             select g;
            Console.WriteLine(groupQuery);

            // Create a new file for each group that was created  
            // Note that nested foreach loops are required to access  
            // individual items with each group.  
            foreach (var g in groupQuery)
            {
                // Create the new file name.  
                string fileName = @"D:\FileSplitter\" + g.Key + ".txt";

                // Output to display.  
                Console.WriteLine(g.Key);

                // Write file.  
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
                {
                    foreach (var item in g)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item);
                        // Output to console for example purposes.  
                        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", item);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Keep console window open in debug mode.  
            Console.WriteLine("Files have been written. Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Reading the contents of the source file? Splitting that contents by newlines into an Array/Collection? Determining which elements belong to which group? Writing the elements to the output file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-split-a-file-into-many-files-by-using-groups-linq, seems to be the documentation that points me in the right direction.  I'm having trouble understanding how I would write the correct pseudo query for the variable groupQuery in the documentation so that it would work for my file above.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan each `line` of the origin file and decide to which file (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`) you should write it:

```
// Open writers for each file
using StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file1.txt");
using StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file2.txt");
using StreamWriter file3 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file3.txt");

// scan original file
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\original.txt")) {
  // decide where to write the line...
  var writer = 
      line.EndsWith("|File1") ? file1
    : line.EndsWith("|File2") ? file2
    : file3;

  // ... and write
  writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: This only works if I have a few files.  In the actual problem I am working with, I have hundreds of files.  Please see real solution above.

Comment: @Zach Lau: If you have *a lot of files*, please *specify this* in the question: I've read "I would like to have **three** files." (**bold** is mine, D.B.) and so I've proposed the solution which uses the restriction. In the most general case (multi Gigabyte file which doesn't fit RAM and thus `GroupBy` is not an answer) I would read file chunk after chunk, read lines within chunk, open files when required and close all the files on the chunk end.

Comment: I've posted the solution up at the top.  It doesn't matter whether I have three files or hundreds of files, we should choose the best solution.  I also posted the link up top of the solution I was looking at and trying to modify to fit my scenario.  If you had bothered to read, you would have seen a straight forward problem with a best solution.  As it was I figured it out without really any help because everyone complained about the question being asked.  This really wasn't that hard that someone couldn't have pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code

```
 string currentfilename
 file currentfile
 while read line from file
     split line on |
     if filename != current filename
         close currentfile
         currentfilename = filename
         open filename
     write line to currentfile
```